# Loading gif on link_to with ajax rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a link_to that renders slow due to parsing a lot of JSON data in the show. I'm having issues implementing a loading gif on the index page while the destination page finishes loading. It shows the loading icon, but does not go to the show page and finishes its animation.

CSS

```
#loading-indicator {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}
```

Index view

```
<img src="/images/loading.gif" id="loading-indicator" style="display:none" />
<% @list.each do |l| %>
<%= link_to l.name, list_path(l), :remote => true %>
<% end %>
```

script

```
<script>
$(document).ajaxSend(function(event, request, settings) {
  $('#loading-indicator').show();
});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings) {
  $('#loading-indicator').hide();
});
</script>
```

Comment: u can use `gem 'blockuijs-rails'` for apply loader

Answer (score 0):

in your gemfile

```
gem 'blockuijs-rails',  :git => 'https://github.com/BoTreeConsultingTeam/blockuijs-rails.git'
```

in your js

```
applyLoader: function () {
    $.blockUI({message: '<img src="/ring-alt.svg" width="75px" />',
      css: {
      border: 'none',
      padding: '15px',
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      '-webkit-border-radius': '10px',
      '-moz-border-radius': '10px',
      opacity: .5,
      color: '#fff'
    }});
  },
  ajaxLoader: function () {
    $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
      applyLoader();
    }).ajaxStop(function () {
      $.unblockUI();
    });
  },
```